# python parameter validation -pyspark dataframe filter string

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, pyspark

I have requirement to pass the where clause string directly to the input dataframe to filter the input records.
The filter_string with column name and the value to filter will be in the below format:

```
Ex 1: "(col('clm1') == '201')"
Ex 2: "(col('clm1') == '101') & (col('dim2') == '201')"

Scenario: If filter_string = "(col('clm1') == '201')"   # In the correct format
   df_output = df_input.filter(eval(filter_str)
```

Now, i want to write the python syntax to raise an exception of the filter string if itis not in the above format. How can i do that?

Comment: You didn't provide actual python code. If "what" is not in the above format? You have multiple strings, which one are you talking about? Can you give multiple examples of filter_str? I see you using a eval(), that is typically a bad sign.

Comment: You can consider Ex 1, and have to write some code to check the syntax of the parameter which is passed in above format or not, if not i have to raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand what you have written, but am having trouble. In general, you should not mix "text" and "code" together. It confuses people that are trying to read your work. The words "Scenario:" and "Ex 1:" are not code and shouldn't be in your code block.

It sounds like you want to raise an exception, based on a matching string. Here is how to do that:

```
filter_string = "(col('clm1') == '201')" # Could be something else too. 
check_string  = "(col('clm1') == '201')"

if not other_string == check_string:
    raise TypeError(f"The string you provided, {filter_string}, is not valid.")

df_output = df_input.filter(eval(filter_string))
```